# How to access a Django model instance after it has already been saved?

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship

I have 2 models, one called MyProfile and another for items for sale.

In my views I am trying to create an item for sale, but when I set author (which is a foreignkey to MyProfile, I get an error.

views.py

```
    active_user = MyProfile.objects.filter(user=david)
    form.author = active_user
```

error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<MyProfile: david test test None>]>":  
"Entry.author" must be a "MyProfile" instance.
```

I think the problem here is that I am trying to pass an instance of MyProfile to form.author, but instead I am passing a QuerySet.  So my question is how do I pass the object?

I am working on a project in django and trying to completely bypass the django user model, so please keep this in mind when answering.  I am NOT trying to use the included django User model, all I'm trying to figure out is a solution for passing the MyProfile instance to form.author since this is a ForeignKey field.

I thought I could just pass it via request.session, but I got an error about serializing this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `filter`, which returns a list of all results, rather than `get`, which returns only one:

```
active_user = MyProfile.objects.get(user=david)
```

The foreign key field is expecting an instance of MyProfile, not a list. Keep in mind this will raise a `MyProfile.DoesNotExist` exception if no results are found.

This is about the same thing as filtering and just grabbing the first element:

```
active_user = MyProfile.objects.filter(user=david)[0]
# OR
active_user = MyProfile.objects.filter(user=david).first()
```